# how -f , -s options work with the uniq command?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, uniq

According to manual page for uniq

the -f option is for skipping fields

the -s option for skipping characters

Can someone explain with relevant examples, how actually these two options work?

Comment: -1. It seems you are listing all UNIX commands, and asking questions to clarify the manpage for you. Apart from google, I suggest http://unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

Vanilla `uniq`:

```
/tmp$ cat > foo
foo
foo
bar
bar
bar
baz
baz
/tmp$ uniq foo
foo
bar
baz
```

`uniq -s` to skip over the first character:

```
/tmp$ cat > bar
1foo
2foo
3bar
4bar
5bar
6baz
7baz
/tmp$ uniq -s1 bar
1foo
3bar
6baz
```

`uniq -f` to skip over the first field of the input (here, hosts):

```
/tmp$ cat > baz
127.0.0.1 foo
192.168.1.1 foo
example.com bar
www.example.com bar
localhost bar
gateway1 baz
192.168.1.254 baz
/tmp$ uniq -f1 baz
127.0.0.1 foo
example.com bar
gateway1 baz
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks clear to me but here you go anyway.

`-f` skips fields. So

```
(ol)noufal@sanitarium% echo "a b c\nd e c" | uniq -c
      1 a b c
      1 d e c
```

prints two separate lines but if you skip the first two fields (-f2) and compare only the last,

```
(ol)noufal@sanitarium% echo "a b c\nd e c" | uniq -c -f2
      2 a b c
```

they're both the same.

Similarly,

```
(ol)noufal@sanitarium% echo "abc\ndec" | uniq -c
      1 abc
      1 dec
(ol)noufal@sanitarium% echo "abc\ndec" | uniq -c -s2
      2 abc
```

We skip the first two characters here (rather than fields).

As for the definition of fields, the manual has that.

> A field is a run of blanks (usually spaces and/or TABs), then
>   non-blank characters.