# unix command to print every 2nd line of duplicate

Tags: unix

I have a text file that has 110132 lines and looks like this,

b3694658:heccc 238622
b3769025:heccc 238622
b3694659:heccc 238623
b3769026:heccc 238623
b3694660:heccc 238624
b3769027:heccc 238624
b3694661:heccc 238625
b3769028:heccc 238625

Notice that every 2nd line has a duplicate entry at heccc etc., i want an output that only has the 2nd occurrence of the duplicate, so it would look like this,

b3769025:heccc 238622
b3769026:heccc 238623
b3769027:heccc 238624
b3769028:heccc 238625

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It appears that you are just looking to output unique values. If so just so `cat textfile | sort | uniq`

Comment: Ok yes, cat sort and uniq gets me what i want  Thanks!

Comment: Great! I have added that as an answer. There's another answer added also. Please feel free to mark one of them as answered to give closure to your question.

Comment: Is there a reason why none of your questions have been marked with an answer?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are just looking to output unique values. If that is so, just do this:

```
cat textfile | sort | uniq
```

Answer (score 0):

```
uniq -f1 file.txt
```

should do in this case.
see [how -f , -s options work with the uniq command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8078769/how-f-s-options-work-with-the-uniq-command)

Comment: Ok that helps some, because i now have a list of what I'm keeping in the data but I need a list of what I'm removing.  I need a list of the 2nd duplicate for the entries, for example it would contain

Comment: b3769023:heccc 238617  b3769024:heccc 238620

Comment: how bout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8078769/how-f-s-options-work-with-the-uniq-command

Comment: sort -r -k 2 -u file.txt